# Resistance with scroll in HorizontalPager in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, jetpack-compose-accompanist

I have implemented `HorizontalPager` with `TabRow` in my project. My HorizontalPager uses default fling behaviour from `PagerDefaults.flingBehavior(state)`. I have not overridden the fling behavior.

This is how the code looks like:

```
    val pagerState = rememberPagerState()
    HorizontalPager(
                count = profileState.tabs.size,
                state = pagerState
            ) {..grid item..}
```

I have to scroll very hard to scroll between the pager items. I want the pager to scroll to next/previous screen on even slight scroll.

After debugging and logging, I found that `initialVelocity` in `performFling` method is coming out to be `-0.0` (same for left and right fling) all the time for some reason.

Comment: If you won't find an answer here, you can [ask](https://github.com/google/accompanist/issues/new/choose) on Accompanist GitHub

Comment: Have you found a solution for that? I'm having the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

You can use (with Accompanist version: accompanist-pager:0.24.8-beta):

```
  HorizontalPager(
        count = 3,
        state = pagerState,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.Top,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was a horizontal scrollable Row in the pager item. Make it unscrollable.